# Multiple Gallery Posts With Sldiers

Tags: gallery

I'm trying to make multiple gallery posts with Flexslider. The problem is that it only renders slider first time and in the second post there is no slider.
Here is the code I've got so far:

**Main function to retrieve attachment images from post**

```
<?php
    function deo_get_attachment( $num = 1 ){

      $output = '';
      if( has_post_thumbnail() && $num == 1 ): 
        $output = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
      else:
        $attachments = get_posts( array( 
          'post_type'       => 'attachment',
          'posts_per_page'  => $num,
          'orderby'         => 'none',
          'post_parent'     => get_the_ID()
        ) );
        if( $attachments && $num == 1 ):
          foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ):
            $output = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
          endforeach;
        elseif( $attachments && $num > 1 ):
          $output = $attachments;
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

      endif;

      return $output;
    }
?>
```

**Code to display slider:**

```
  <?php if ( deo_get_attachment() ) : 
    $attachments = deo_get_attachment(10);
  ?>
    <div class="entry-slider">
      <div class="flexslider dots-inside">
        <ul class="slides clearfix">

          <?php foreach( $attachments as $attachment ) : ?>
            <li>
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ); ?>" alt="">
              </a>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you need to initialize them separately, via unique ids or classes.

Comment: Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: If you google "multiple flexsliders" you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: If I could find solution in Google, I would not post here. The problem is all the Google solutions related to multiple ID's in jQuery. But in my case I need to initialize all sliders dynamically. And it's not a problem, in HTML you can just use single class and all the sliders will be working with this class. But in WordPress loop it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: If something works in a static html page, then it should work on a WordPress page, there's no difference on the browser side. Without seeing your complete code and how you're invoking the slider, I can't guess what the problem is. Note that javascript and 3rd party tools are off-topic here.

Comment: My full code as above. There is a function to retrieve WordPress gallery attachment images from the post. Then I use this function with a foreach loop to get each image and print it to slider. But it works only once. Javascript is very simple, it's just and initialization of the slider.

Answer (score -1):

I found my mistake. I used the same attachment images for the other post. So, WordPress can't get images that already attached to another gallery.

Comment: very unlikely...

Comment: reading again the answer, your "problem" is that you can not ttach an image to more than one post